# Ввод в TextBox только цифр и английских символов

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как наиболее правильно запретить ввод в TextBox символов любой раскладки кроме английской и цифр. Желательно не сравнивая в цикле каждый символ строки с шаблоном.

---

```
private void validationTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox a = (TextBox)sender;
            if (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.F)
                e.Handled = true;
            //code
        }
```

Comment: А что не так с кодом, который вы привели?

Comment: (За исключением странно заданного и скорее всего неправильного диапазона)

Comment: @VladD Он работает, но допускает ввод символов на любой раскладке

Comment: Ага, понял. Сейчас гляну.

Comment: Да, а что вы хотите делать с Ctrl-V?

Comment: @VladD Вставка не понадобится, но с ней конечно было бы удобнее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У меня работает код, основанный на [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268648/276994):

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="OnPreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="OnPasting"/>
```

```
void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !e.Text.All(IsGood);
}

private void OnPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    var stringData = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));
    if (stringData == null || !stringData.All(IsGood))
        e.CancelCommand();
}

bool IsGood(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return true;
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        return true;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Вставка работает, если в ней нет запрещённых символов.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(
            [In] IntPtr hWnd,
            [Out, Optional] IntPtr lpdwProcessId
            );

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern ushort GetKeyboardLayout(
            [In] int idThread
            );


        private int GetKeyboardLayout()
        {
            return GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero));
        }

        private void validationTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox a = (TextBox)sender;
            if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.Z)
            {
            if ((e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z) && (GetKeyboardLayout() != 1033))
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        else e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: 1033? А если ввод на французской локали?

Comment: У французкой 1036 код, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh825684.aspx

Comment: Ну это да, но ваш код не примет цифры ни на французской, ни на немецкой, ни на китайской локали.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, исправил, теперь принимает

Comment: Окей, а букву `a` на французской локали принимает?